# How to use SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings In a LaunchDaemon on macos?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I use this code to add the certificate from the file to the system keychain and make it as trusted.

```
// Load the certificate from file
           NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/zhuzhengjia/cert.der"];
           if (!certData) {
               NSLog(@"Failed to read the certificate file.");
               return -1;
           }
           
           // Create a certificate object from the data
           SecCertificateRef certRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDataRef)certData);
           if (!certRef) {
               NSLog(@"Failed to create certificate from data.");
               return -1;
           }
           // 3. Add the certificate to the system keychain
                   SecKeychainRef keychain = NULL;
                   OSStatus status = SecKeychainOpen("/Library/Keychains/System.keychain", &keychain);
                   if (status == errSecSuccess) {
                       status = SecCertificateAddToKeychain(certRef, keychain);
                       CFRelease(keychain);
                   }
                   if (status != errSecSuccess) {
                       NSLog(@"Failed to add certificate to keychain: %d", (int)status);
                       CFRelease(certRef);
                       return -1;
                   }

                   // 4. Set trust settings for the certificate
                   status = SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(certRef, kSecTrustSettingsDomainAdmin, NULL);
                   if (status != errSecSuccess) {
                       spdlog::error("Failed to set trust settings: {}", (int)status);
                       CFRelease(certRef);
                       return -1;
                   }
           
           CFRelease(certRef);
```

If I run the executatle via command line like sudo ./program. It works well. However, If I run this code in a LaunchDaemon. SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings return -60007. Why this happens? How should I make it work in a daemon process?